# Swift: Remove ads different scene in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mopub

I'm using the MoPub banner ad, I added the following code to my View Controller's viewDidLoad:

```
     self.adView.delegate = self
    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height,
        MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.width, MOPUB_BANNER_SIZE.height)
    self.view.addSubview(self.adView)
    self.adView.loadAd()
```

But it makes the ad visible in all the scenes when I only want it to be visible in the main menu scene.

How do I remove the ad in the scenes that  I don't want it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best way to do this, but it is probably the simplest. You could use an `NSNotification` to broadcast a message to your `ViewController` whenever you wish to show or hide you banner.

For instance if you add an "observer" in your `ViewController` on `init` or `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
  self, 
  selector: "hideBannerAd", 
  name: "hideAd", 
  object: nil)
```

To make the `ViewController` listen for a message called `"hideAd"` and then execute a method called `hideBannerAd`.

Then implement this method:

```
func hideBannerAd(){
  self.adView.hidden = true
}
```

Be sure to remove the observer on `deinit`, this isn't likely to be an issue what with the persistance of a `ViewController` in `SpriteKit` but it's good practice.

```
deinit{
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Then, when you want to show or hide the view, for example on a scene transition or game over method, you can implement this `hideBannerAd` method by triggering the observer using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideAd", object: nil)
```

And the banner should hide. This can then be repeated for a similar `showBannerAd` method by setting the `hidden` property to `false`, or you can have a single method that simply toggles the hidden property using `adView.hidden = !adView.hidden`.

I hope this helps.